# adding object from a listbox to another

Tags: c#, database, listbox, ef-code-first

My problem is the following : I have two `ListBoxe`s. In the first, I store products, which can be ordered, and the second is the cart of the customer. So a product has a Quantity property, and I have a `NumericUpDown`, where the customer can change the number of the ordered products.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //puts selectedproduct to the cart
{
    if (listBox1.SelectedItem == null || (int)numericUpDown1.Value == 0 ||
        (listBox1.SelectedItem as Product).Quantity < (int)numericUpDown1.Value) return;

    foreach (Product item in listBox2.Items)
    {
        if (item.ID == (listBox1.SelectedItem as Product).ID)
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    listBox2.Items.Add(new Product { Name = (listBox1.SelectedItem as Product).Name,
                                 Price = (listBox1.SelectedItem as Product).Price,
                                 Quantity = (int)numericUpDown1.Value});

    (listBox1.SelectedItem as Product).Quantity -= (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
}
```

This works great, except, it adds a new item to my Products table. The thing I want to do is adding to the customers cart the selected product with the selected quantity, not adding a new item to products table, and reduce the ordered products quantity with the numericupdown1.value. I am using EF Code First Database, looks like:

```
public class Order
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }

    public virtual Account account { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Product> products { get; set; }        
}

public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long Price { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Order> orders { get; set; }       
}
```

And here is the saving method:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    List<Product> p = new List<Product>();
    foreach (Product item in listBox2.Items)
    {
        p.Add(item);
    }
    Variables.Db.orders.Add(new Order { account = Variables.Currentuser, products = p });
    Variables.Db.SaveChanges(); //Variables.Db is my CodeFirst Database
}
```

I've tried many ways, for example:

```
int q = (listBox1.SelectedItem as Product).Quantity;
(listBox1.SelectedItem as Product).Quantity = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
listBox2.Items.Add(listBox1.SelectedItem);

(listBox1.SelectedItem as Product).Quantity = q - (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
```

but the last line changes the listbox2 objects quantity back to the same as the listbox1s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the same entity (`Product`) for two different purposes (product and order item) that is just wrong.

The first behavior you see is the consequence of creating new `Product` objects for any order, and the second one is because you are using the same product object in two listboxes.

The correct way to do this is to create a new entity for order item:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long Price { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public virtual List<OrderItem> ordersItems { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }

    public virtual Account account { get; set; }
    public virtual List<OrderItem> Items { get; set; }        
}

public class OrderItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public long TotalPrice { get; set; } // It is better to hold the price. What if you later changed the product price?
}
```

Then you can easily handle the purchase:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //puts selectedproduct to the cart
{
    Product p = listBox1.SelectedItem as Product;
    int q = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
    if (p == null || q == 0 || p.Quantity < q)
        return;

    foreach (Product item in listBox2.Items)
    {
        if (item.ID == p.ID)
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    listBox2.Items.Add(new OrderItem { Product = p, Quantity = q, TotalPrice = p.Price * q });
    p.Quantity -= q;
}


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Order o = new Order() { account = Variables.Currentuser, Items = new List<Order>() };
    foreach (OrderItem item in listBox2.Items)
    {
        o.Items.Add(item);
    }
    Variables.Db.orders.Add(o);
    Variables.Db.SaveChanges(); //Variables.Db is my CodeFirst Database
}
```

Did you also notice the cleaner code? :)

One more thing: Please always use meaningful names for your controls and class fields: `btnSave`, `btnAddToCart` and `numQuantity` are good candidates.